# Repeat field based on quantity in Gravity Forms

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Im trying to setup a form with Gravity forms that automatically populates the field "Name of person" based on a quantity field.

So lets say a user sets product quantity to 1:
Then the list field shows 1 row with Name | Last name | Date of birth

But when a users sets product quantity to 4 im trying to achieven that automatically 4 rows are displayed like:

Row 1.
Name | Last name | Date of birth

Row 2.
Name | Last name | Date of birth

Row 3.
Name | Last name | Date of birth

Row 4.
Name | Last name | Date of birth

Im really hoping somebody can help me out with this issue.
Im stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We have a free snippet for that here:

https://gravitywiz.com/set-number-of-list-field-rows-by-field-value/

For your setup, you'll want to target the Product's quantity input:

````
new GWAutoListFieldRows( array(
    'form_id' => {FORM_ID},
    'list_field_id' => {LIST_FIELD_ID},
    'input_html_id' => '#input_{PRODUCT_FIELD_ID}_3'
) );```
````